# Type Error data to string is not a function vs code terminal showing a type error explain the condition i am new to the node js ,jus explain the error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let fs = require('fs')
let data = fs.readFileSync('example.txt');

if (data)console.log(data.toString());
consol.log('program Ended');*
```

this was my code
and this is the error my terminal showing to me

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\apna college\index.js:4
console.log(data.tostring());
             ^

TypeError: data.tostring is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\apna college\index.js:4:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\apna college>
```

i am very new in node js so please anyone can explain me what is the problem that will be very helpful

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code you posted. `tostring` should have an uppercase `S`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second parameter, `"utf-8",` and it should work.

```
let fs = require('fs')
let data = fs.readFileSync('example.txt','utf-8');
if (data)console.log(data.toString());
console.log('program Ended');*
```